# How do I enter the Colosseum on Final Fantasy Brave Exvius?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

When I go to the Colosseum on Final Fantasy Brave Exvius, it won't let me participate. I am able to go inside the main building, but I can't actually do anything.

I went to the receptionist and he told me "*put on a show*" and that's it, I can't do anything and I can't figure this out.

Comment: Gee Wondercricket, thanks for the edit. I swear I get more edits on this than actual answers, I mean, not trying to be a jerk or anything but if I wanted a spellcheck, I'd go to google

Comment: Users with enough reputation are allowed to edit content. This is so that content can be clarified and spelling fixed, to the benefit of all. If you don't like it...well, its still going to happen. Its not about you; it's about content.

Comment: @Liriouslithium My initial edit was to correct the tag, but Frank is also correct - it is about the content. Questions are harder to answer if they are harder read

Answer (score 2):

Once you reach the town of Grandshelt, then your Home screen will allow you to enter the colosseum.  It's one of the options near the bottom, alongside the World map and upgrading your Espers.  If you've gone through the Vortex and talked to the right moogle, it's an option under the Arena.  Otherwise, it's on it's own, just called the Colosseum.